# Does Liouville's Theorem work in real analysis? 

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Liouville's Theorem states that every bounded entire function must be constant. Does it work in real analysis? Justify your answer!
I asked it because Liouville's Theorem is proved by complex analysis.

Comment: What examples of analytic real functions do you know?

Comment: $X^2 + y^2 =r^2$

Comment: That is not a function, but an implicit equation.

Comment: *Entire function* is a concept from complex analysis, so one would have to clarify what your question means. But think $\sin x$, or $e^{-x^2}$.

Comment: Is the reciprocal of a polynomial with no real zeros real analytic? Is it bounded? (Hint: you may use complex analysis to prove that such a function is real analytic.)

Comment: entire functions are imposed the Cauchy–Riemann condition. However there's no such a constraint to real functions.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Actually it does work in real analysis. The question is only which condition replaces the "entire" because it is certainly not true for all real-valued functions (take $\sin(x)$ as Chandru states). However, if a real-valued function $f$ is [harmonic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function) which means that:

$$\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_1^2} +\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_2^2} +\cdots +\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_n^2} = 0$$

It actually has the Liouville Property, isn't that neat?

Comment: How, so ? I mean how can we prove it ?

Answer (score 6):

Take $f(x)=\sin{x}$. clearly $|f| \leq 1$ is bounded and entire but is not constant

Comment: What do you mean with entire here?

Comment: @wildidildlife-it means it is analytic everywhere

Comment: @Victor In the context of functions $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$, "entire" is standard terminology for functions "analytic everywhere". However, in the context of functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, I think most people would use "analytic everywhere" rather than "entire". I think people prefer to reserve "entire" for complex analysis.